# .htaccess - Configuring an Apache server for Memento

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, memento

I try to configure an `Apache` server to add an `HTTP Link header` pointing at a `Memento` TimeGates url

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
RewriteRule ^/(.*) - [E=ORIGURI:%{HTTP_HOST}/$1]

RewriteRule ^/(.*) - [E=ORIGQRY:]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^/(.*) - [E=ORIGQRY:?%{QUERY_STRING}]

RewriteRule ^/(.*) - [E=ORIGPROTO:http]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) - [E=ORIGPROTO:https]

Header always set Link 
    "<http://purl.org/memento/timegate/%{ORIGPROTO}e://%{ORIGURI}e%{ORIGQRY}e>;rel=timegate"

.
.
.
```

unchanged from: http://www.mementoweb.org/tools/apache/

I am testing the code on `XAMPP` server but the response sent by the server is:

```
.
.
.
Link    <http://purl.org/memento/timegate/(null)://(null)(null)>;rel=timegate
Server  Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
.
.
.
```

What is wrong with the htaccess?

**EDIT 1**

Removing the leading slashes as suggested by Jon Lin :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} FALSE
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGURI:$1]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGQRY:]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGQRY:?%{QUERY_STRING}]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGPROTO:http]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGPROTO:https]
Header always set Link "<http://purl.org/memento/timegate/%{ORIGPROTO}e://%{ORIGURI}e%{ORIGQRY}e>;rel=timegate"
```

The new response sent by the server:

```
Link <http://purl.org/memento/timegate/http://(null)>;rel=timegate
```

As we can see the protocole is parsed but not the rest of the url, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring an Apache server for Memento

**1. HTTP Headers Using .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGPROTO:http]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGPROTO:https]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGURI:%{HTTP_HOST}]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^\s?]+)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ORIGQRY:%1]

Header always set Link "<http://purl.org/memento/timegate/%{ORIGPROTO}e://%{ORIGURI}e%{ORIGQRY}e>;rel=timegate"
```

See: [htaccess - how to capture the current rewrited url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856511/htaccess-how-to-capture-the-current-rewrited-url)

**2. HTTP Headers Using PHP**

```
   function get_canonical_url($proto='http://'){
        $canonical_url = $proto;
        if($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
                $canonical_url .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] .  $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        } 
        else {
                $canonical_url.=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
        return $canonical_url;
    }

    header('Link: <'.get_canonical_url().'>; rel="canonical"');
```

Resources: http://moz.com/blog/how-to-advanced-relcanonical-http-headers

Answer (score 1):

Your rules have this pattern `^/(.*)` which will never match if the rules are in an htaccess file. Mod_rewrite strips off the leading slash from the URI when applying rules in an htaccess file. Remove the leading slashes in your patterns:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGURI:%{HTTP_HOST}/$1]
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks, the new link is now <http://purl.org/memento/timegate/http://(null)>;rel=timegate when it should be <http://purl.org/memento/timegate/http://localhost/mysite.html>;rel=timegate could you provide with more advises please?