# htaccess - how to capture the current rewrited url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to capture the current **rewrited url** via `.htaccess` in order to create to a custom HTTP Link header.

the script url :

```
http://localhost/index.php
```

the rewrited url :

```
http://localhost/news
```

the htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(news)$ index.php?&m=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGPROTO:http]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGURI:%{HTTP_HOST}]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGQRY:%{REQUEST_URI}]
```

the output:

```
ORIGPROTO = http
ORIGURI = localhost
ORIGQRY = index.php
```

I am expecting ORIGQRY to be equal to 'news'

My question is how to capture the current rewrited url via htaccess?

**EDIT 1**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGPROTO:http]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGURI:%{HTTP_HOST}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)[^/]$
RewriteRule . %1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(/{2,})(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)_(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1-%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\º(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\!(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\,(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\'(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\"(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\“(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\”(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\((.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\)(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\[(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\](.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\{(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\}(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\:(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1-%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\+(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1-%2 [R=301,L]

#avoid uppercase & accented

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(A|Â|â|Æ|æ|À|à|Å|å|Ã|ã|Ä|ä)(.*?)$
RewriteRule . %1a%3 [R=301,L]

.
.
.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(news)/?$ index.php?&m=$1 [NC,QSA,E=ORIGQRY:$1,L]

#404 page

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pt=404&acc=404_page [L]
Header always set Link "<http://cache_api.com/%{ORIGPROTO}e://%{ORIGURI}e%{ORIGQRY}e>;rel=timegate"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules are executed in the order of their presence in .htacces. Here your first rule is modifying `REQUEST_URI` to `/index.php`.

**FIX:** Change the order of your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGPROTO:http]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=ORIGURI:%{HTTP_HOST}]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^\s?]+)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ORIGQRY:%1]

Header always set Link "<http://cache_api.com/%{ORIGPROTO}e://%{ORIGURI}e/%{ORIGQRY}e>;rel=timegate"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(news)/?$ index.php?m=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, I have also tried this but it dosen't change the value of ORIGQRY and surprisingly $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']='news'

Comment: No instead of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` you need to check `$_SERVER['ORIGQRY']`

Comment: Just run `phpinfo();` in your PHP code to see which server variable has it. On my server it is `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_ORIGQRY"]` that has `news` value.

Comment: Also dump your full .htaccess if your have other rules also.

Comment: I confirme $_SERVER["REDIRECT_ORIGQRY"] = news

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44239/discussion-between-rafasashi-and-anubhava)